# How to find which sentence is having the maximum number of words using PySpark RDD api?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to get the sentence with maximum number of words. I have very little experience with PySpark and having trouble with this.

Let me list down the steps I followed.

1. Created a text_file which contains say below sentences:
   Hello World
   This is Subhayan
   This is my first Spark program
   I am using Spark with Python
   Hello World
   This is Subhayan
   This is my first Spark program
   I am using Spark with Python
2. Read the text file as an RDD (have to use RDD only)
3. Wrote the below code for getting the count of maximum number of words in a line

   ```
    def str_split(line):
       return line.split(' ')
    splitted_rdd = text_rdd.map(str_split) 
    def word_pair(word):
       return (word, len(word))
    word_pair_rdd = splitted_rdd.map(word_pair)
    m = max(word_pair_rdd.values().collect())
   ```

I understand that this might not be the way to do it but I am not getting how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example,
collect() is a dangerous operation in spark. collect() forces to get all the data to master node and I would highly recommend not using this unless debugging.

```
m = max(word_pair_rdd.values().collect())
```

Here is something that should work for your problem statement
`get the sentence with a maximum number of words with only RDD API`

```
topK=1

## Sample Data / Replace this with read_file
data_rdd = sc.parallelize(["Stackoverflow is a question answering platform","Stackoverflow is Best","Spark Pyspark"])

## Step1: input: Document, output: (document, document_word_count)
tuple_sentence_wordslength=data_rdd.map(lambda sentence: (sentence,len(sentence.split(' '))))

## Step2: (document, document_word_count) => take the top K based on word_count
tuple_sentence_wordslength.takeOrdered(topK, key = lambda sentence_wordslength: -sentence_wordslength[1])
```